# WPF Window still open even after closing

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0

I have a WPF window which is still present in `Application.Current.Windows` even when it is closed. I have tried closing it using both the Window close button and `this.Close()`, however, when I iterate through the items in the `Application.Current.Windows`, it is still present. What could be the issue? There are no threads running, if that helps. The visibility of the window is `Collapsed` and the `IsActive` property is `false`. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The Window reference should be removed, [as per MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.windows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> A Window reference is automatically added to Windows as soon as a
>   window is instantiated on the user interface (UI) thread; windows that
>   are created by worker threads are not added. A Window reference is
>   automatically removed after its Closing event has been handled and
>   before its Closed event is raised.

So I'd question how you're closing it and where you're checking for it's reference. I'd suggest you're likely doing it/checking it wrong. If you could show us some actual logic maybe it would be more clear.

Comment: A link to MSDN? I would consider link rot.

Comment: Except I _contain_ the relevant part _in my answer_. Seriously, this is pathetic, Roy. Very childish - and [in retaliation to this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22145619/263681), so anyone can see through you.

Comment: @GrantThomas Sorry for the late reply. As I mentioned, I am closing it using the Window close button. I also have a button on the page, on click of which I'm closing the window by invoking Close(). I still haven't figured out what the actual issue is. Weirdly, all properties of the window are null, except one, drilling down on that leads to a Dispatch object. Now I'm just going through all the windows in Application.Current.Windows and if the Title and Name is blank, I'm closing it again by invoking Close(). This has fixed the issue for the time being.

Comment: @GrantThomas Now I'm just going through all the windows in Application.Current.Windows WHEN THE WINDOWCLOSED EVENT IS INVOKED and if the Title and Name is blank, I'm closing it again by invoking Close(). This has fixed the issue for the time being.