# Asp.net Web Api query string parameter with dash

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have an `Web.Api` search method which receives the following parameter:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "", Name = "search")]
public class SearchParameters
{
    [DataMember(Name = "property-name")]
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
}
```

In the `Controller`, i have this action:

```
[HttpGet]
public void Search([FromUri]SearchParameters request)
{
    var parameters = 1;
}
```

I am trying to create a friendly name for `PropertyName` property (`property-name`), but the model binder doesn't recognizes the parameter:

```
/api/changeLog/search?propertyName=asd  // Works

/api/changeLog/search?property-name=asd // Doesn't work
```

Is dash a reserved query string character? or i am using it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, it is reserved as defined in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986 (the standard page for RFC 3986, which defines Uniform Resource Identifiers, otherwise known as URI's).

**EDIT** I was too quick -- I misread a '=' for a '-' in the list of reserved characters. It seems that the dash is indeed listed with the unreserved characters. It makes no sense to me but that is just my opinion... This RFC being the official standard, you would expect servers to respect the format -- and possibly IIS does, but probably .NET doesn't (see below).
**End of Edit**

Generally query strings follow the format  ITEM '&' ITEM... where you can define ITEM as VARIABLE '=' VALUE.

But just like in programming languages, VARIABLE cannot contain any characters that make it hard to parse the name or to map it to a variable. So characters such as '*' and '-' cannot be used in variable names.

**EDIT** In the case of .NET, I would expect that this is because .NET attempts to map a query string parameter name to a method parameter name. But then they should allow the use of a dash in the `[DataMember]` attribute. As this is not the case, I assume they did not consult the RFC when they were building this functionality... Would anyone care to elaborate? **End of edit**

Other sources for the same information:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier
- http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt

Comment: @RoyDictus: I cannot seem to find '-' in the reserved delimiters list in the RFC. Are you sure it's reserved? In fact it appears in the `unreserved` list on p13.

Comment: You're right, I misread the '=' for '-'. It still makes no sense to use this character I think, but apparently the definition does allow for it.